# Semantic UI Ratings not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I cannot make the ratings element displayed. It simply does not appear. All other things work fine enough

I have linked these properly:

- Semantic UI CSS (http://semantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.min.css)
- Semantic UI JS (http://semantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.min.js)
- JQuery (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js)

And I use it like this:

```
<div class="ui star rating" data-rating="4"></div>
```

Do I need to do something else to make it work?

Comment: Well the semantic links you provided do not load for me, could that be why? Or is that just me.

Comment: This works http://semantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.min.css

Comment: I posted `https` instead of `http` sorry.

Comment: Are you calling the rating in your jQuery? `$('.rating').rating();`
;

Comment: It is not even displaying.

Comment: But that is probably why.. you need to tell `jQuery` to load the rating bar in the `.rating` div.

Comment: If you do not have a JS file, include this on the page you want the rating to show: `<script>$(document).ready(function(){$(".rating").rating();});</script>`

Comment: Everything you need to get it working is here: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/rating.html#/usage

Comment: Hey! using the script worked like a charm. post it as an answer. I didn't know that you had to *script* to **show** it.

Comment: Great! Will do, gimme a few mins ;)

Comment: If you need more info on js/jquery or anything just let me know and I will include it in the answer! Happy programming!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initialize the `rating` plugin on the `.rating` `div` element in `jQuery`.

Either add this to your `.js` file:

```
// This waits for the DOM to load correctly before changing elements
$(document).ready(function(){
    // All your normal JS code goes in here
    $(".rating").rating();
});
```

Or if you don't have a `.js` file you can just include this `Javascript/jQuery` on each page the rating needs displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$(".rating").rating();});</script>
```

And that will give you the same effect.

You can also specify different options within the initialization:

```
$('.rating')
  .rating({
    initialRating: 3,
    maxRating: 5
  })
;
```

You can find a list of options and other examples here: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/rating.html

Comment: I have another question - how can you make it 7/8/9/10 stars?

Comment: Please correct me if this does not work, but try adding `data-max-rating="10"` to the `<div class="ui star rating" data-rating="4"></div>`

Comment: Oh it was the *max* and i kept modifying `data-rating` in vain. Thanks again.

Comment: I am quite new to Web Development.

Comment: That's okay! You now know how to initialize jquery :) enjoy!